# Is it possible to make a *portrait* <video> tag responsive in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, video, wordpress-theming

[important note: this only affects self-hosted `<video>` tags, not youtube or vimeo iframes]

So I'm embedding in the page cellphone videos with a **vertical ratio** (portrait) (typically 720px width and 1280px height).

Everything works, except the videos will not adapt to the page. The width will fit, but the user needs to scroll up and down while the video plays to appreciate what is being shown.

I've tried all the CSS tricks to make the video div responsive, but it won't work.

The videos are wrapped into a div which reads as so:

```
.wp-video-shortcode, video, .mejs-mediaelement {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    max-height:100% !important;
}
```

But to no effect (only the width appears to adapt as the page changes size!).

IF I manually alter the width and hight in the shortcode, as so:

```
[video width="720" height="1280" mp4="http://url.mp4" autoplay="true" poster="http://url.jpg"][/video]
```

becoming

```
[video width="340" height="680" mp4="http://url.mp4" autoplay="true" poster="http://url.jpg"][/video]
```

The video gets smaller, **but still will not adapt to the page.**

I think I've figured why...? Tell me if I am off track:

The whole premise of how the `<video>` embed in Wordpress is sized, seems to be based on `width`: there is even a global variable called `$content_width` for this purpose, while there is no `$content_height`.

Specifically, this is what happens in the `wp_video_shortcode` function:

```
global $content_width;

// if the video is bigger than the theme
        if ( ! empty( $content_width ) && $atts['width'] > $content_width ) {
            $atts['height'] = round( ( $atts['height'] * $content_width ) / $atts['width'] );
            $atts['width'] = $content_width;
        }
```

as you can see above, wp only seems to be checking the video only against the width of the page.

How can this be worked out?

Answer (score 5):

The short answer I think is that WordPress can't do responsive portrait (video) embeds 'Out of the box'.

However, you could achieve what you want in WordPress with some custom coding. The following is adapted from the Twitter Bootstrap Framework, in particular as documented here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed

The change I've made is so that it works for a portrait oriented (video) embed, of 9:16 aspect ratio (given your video evidently is 720px x 1280px (= 9:16 aspect ratio)).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-9by16">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="[URL to your video]"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.embed-responsive {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.embed-responsive-9by16 {
    padding-bottom: 177.78%;
}

.embed-responsive .embed-responsive-item, .embed-responsive embed, .embed-responsive iframe, .embed-responsive object, .embed-responsive video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/c4akmfxd/ (the URL for the iframe in this example is the first URL that I could think of that is both responsive and available via HTTPS (necessary to have HTTPS with JSFiddle) (it's a website I built called 'Ten Moons')).

The `<div` with class `container` is just an example - it can be whatever you want that has an appropriate width to put your portrait embed inside - and could be your `<body>` tag, or any part of your web page.

In case you need a different aspect ratio, just change (or create a new CSS class for) the padding-bottom for the `.embed-responsive-9by16` CSS class. You can work out the percentage required as:
`height / width * 100` (in your case: `1280 / 720 * 100 = 177.78%`).

How you get this in WordPress is a bit of another matter - and largely depends on your setup. You could edit the CSS file to add these CSS classes; to get the HTML in your page could be another matter, as WordPress sometimes "rewrites" HTML that you paste in the HTML view and strips out things that you want. But the JSFiddle proves that you can achieve a responsive portrait embed.

FWIW though, I don't think you'd need to do anything with the PHP variable `$content_width`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an iframe?  The code below will not require any CSS file editing.

```
<div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">
<iframe type="video/mp4" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BXFLBj5y2A0" frameborder="5px" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
</div>
```

Depending upon your user role WordPress might delete the iframe code when you save it. This will happen if you are for example an Author.  See if you can be changed to an Editor Role

Answer (score 0):

I have a diferent approach, very simple one, leave here just in case:

```
<div class="image-cover" style="background-image: url('YOUR_PORTAIT_IMG'); ">
<video controls class="d-block w-100" poster="TRANSPARENT_1px.png"> 
  <source src="YOUR_VIDEO_SRC" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
```

Where the class .image-cover is:

```
.image-cover {
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll; }
```

And classes "d-block" is display:block; and "w-100" is width:100%; (bootstrap)

That way, no matter the video size, since the portrait is nothing (transparent png), the image visible by the viewer allays will fill the entire area (cover).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to dynamically calculate the width of the video via JS, so the ratio is always the same:

```js
function setWidth() {
  const vc = document.querySelector('.video-container');
  vc.style.width = `${vc.offsetHeight * 0.5625}px`;
}

setWidth();

window.addEventListener("resize", setWidth);
```

```css
.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 85%;
}

iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
    <iframe 
        width="315" 
        height="560" 
        src="<your-url-here>"
    ></iframe>
</div>
```

You can also check the pen here: https://codepen.io/rotolog/pen/QWzaNqX?editors=1010